# How can I make the modal dialog box by clicking outside of it?

Tags: jquery, iframe, dialog

I know there are similar question/answers out there but I think my situation is unique because it contains an iframe and this is all buried in D3 js. I think this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonday/6FGqN/) contains the answer but can't figure out how to use it in my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pzuyhobc/1/).

Here is the code from mine I'm trying to edit

```
 function click(link) {

        $("#dialog").html('<iframe src="http://www.'+link+'.com"></iframe>').dialog({
     autoOpen: false,
     modal: true
  });

  $("#dialog").dialog('open'); }
```

Comment: What is your exact requirement ?

Comment: are you saying that you want to be able to close the modal by clicking outside of it without a close button?

Comment: Yes, I want to close the modal by clicking anywhere outside of it. Sorry I wasn't clearer.

Comment: I had tired with your code its really strange that its not working.. tried in couple of ways..

Comment: Yeah I tried for over an hour and nothing. I'm not sure what's going on either. The iframe inside the modal box is what's tripping things up I think. Maybe.

Comment: Any ideas? Thanks for the effort so far.